# spring security - how to remove cache control in certain url pattern

Tags: spring, spring-security, cache-control, response-headers

I am trying to filter some url pattern to caching.
What I have attempted is put some codes into `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation.

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    initSecurityConfigService();

    // For cache
    http.headers().defaultsDisabled()
            .cacheControl()
            .and().frameOptions();

    securityConfigService.configure(http,this);
}
```

However this code will effect all of the web application. How can I apply this to certain `URL` or `Content-Type` like `images`.

I have already tried with `RegexRequestMatcher`, but it does not work for me.

```
// For cache
        http.requestMatcher(new RegexRequestMatcher("/page/", "GET"))
                .headers().defaultsDisabled()
                .cacheControl()
                .and().frameOptions();
```

I read this article : [SpringSecurityResponseHeaders](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html), but there is no sample for this case.

Thanks.

P.S. In short, I want to remove `SpringSecurity defaults` for certain url and resources.

Comment: maybe I don't understand your question well. Since you want to add cache control for general requests, why is Spring Security involved in this? Can you try to add a filter for this?

Comment: @Simon Security default settings should valid for general calls, but I want to that option for only `image/*` Types. That is why I want to separate those options.

Comment: I understand this point, but to me, this is very simple with a filter, you can set up some url pattern(in your case image/*) to filter. You just set some headers in the response, then everything should be set. If you relly prefer Spring Security, it has the filter chain, you just add one filter after the last one and set the response

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Simon, dur. I solved this with `Filter` like Simon said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about having multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters? One adapter could have cache controls for certain URLs and another one will not have cache control enabled for those URLs.

Comment: This is additional information to help others. To having multiple `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, have to alter the `@Order` of the implements. Default is hidden, but value is `100` and it must not be duplicated. can refer this [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with `Filter`.
Below is part of my implementation of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. In `onStartup` method override.

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurityFilterChain = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
if(springSecurityFilterChain != null){
    springSecurityFilterChain.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/render/*", "/service/*");
    // I removed pattern url "/image/*" :)
}
```

What I have done is remove `/image/*` from MappingUrlPatterns. 
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: There is another regular way to do this. Use [`WebSecurity#ignoring`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html#ignoring--).

Comment: @dur Thanks. That was what I looking for. bb